# Publishing Google Hangouts App

Tags: google-hangouts, google-console-developer, hangouts-api

I followed the following steps:

1. Verify your account at Chrome Web Store by going to Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard and clicking the "Pay this fee now" link.
2. Fill in the fields in the Google Developers Console by following the instructions at the Google Developers Console fields.
3. Create a client ID. If you haven't already, you must create an OAuth 2.0 client ID in your Google Developers Console project before your app goes public.
4. Hangout button, placing the button on your website. Users then click on the button to start a Hangout with your public application or extension running inside it.

I am a Chrome Web Store verified developer, and I did provide links to terms of service, privacy policy, and support contact information. I also have a web application client ID and a browser app ID.

And yet, when I try to make the Hangouts App public, I keep getting the following error.

"Server Error
Whoops! Our bad.

Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using the "Send feedback" link below. Thanks!

Tracking Number: ...

Send feedback "

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: does the gmail i you used is registered with Google Apps?

Comment: It's a gmail account, but I don't think it is registered w/ Google Apps, should it be?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be broken..
[Can't publish a Hangout app (extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179212/cant-publish-a-hangout-app-extension)

I also made a forum post about, maybe u can help me by upvoting the post:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/hangouts/A8q99AOaJxo;context-place=forum/hangouts