# Not able to publish Hangout On Air Extension - oAuth issue

Tags: oauth, google-plus, hangouts-api

I have built a working Hangout On Air Extension which Im not able to publish to the store due to not being able to create oAuth 2.0 client ID with right values.

When I tried to *save* the API setting with below configuration and *Make public* checked i get an error as below,

*Server Error
Whoops! Our bad.
Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using the "Send feedback" link below. Thanks!*

I have gone through [THIS](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/publishing) and [THIS](http://life.scarygami.net/hangoutapps/) links but I think they both are outdated.

1. I have already verified my account at **Chrome Web Store** which is also the owner of the app.
2. On the **Google Developers Console** I have Google Plus API and Hangout API selected for the project. HoA API has been set to point an xml hosted over HTTP server
3. Create a client ID - This is where Im stuck. I have tried to create *oAuth 2.0 client Id* for *Web application* with *Authorized JavaScript origins* and *Authorized redirect URIs* set to empty - as i dont know what to put and i am not using any of these.
4. Additional OAuth scopes is set to empty as currently. I did set it to below three but it didn't help.

   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/hangout.av
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/hangout.participants.

Can you help me set up oAuth right so that i can push this to store?

Update: The error i get is same as [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120234/publishing-google-hangouts-app) which i stumbled upon later.

Comment: Has anyone yet found any solution?